# How to assign values to a df$column from another df using conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, assign

I have two dataframes :

```
> df1 <- data.frame(date = as.Date( c( "2021-06-01", "2021-06-02", "2021-06-03", "2021-06-04", 
                                      "2021-06-05", "2021-06-06", "2021-06-07", "2021-06-08", 
                                      "2021-06-09", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-11", "2021-06-12",
                                      "2021-06-13") ), 
                   temperature = c( 17, 30, 28, 29, 16, 21, 20, 11, 28, 29, 25, 26, 19) )
```

and

```
> df2 <- data.frame( ID = c( 1 : 4 ), 
                    date.pose = as.Date(c("2021-06-01", "2021-06-03", "2021-06-06", "2021-06-10") ),
                    date.withdrawal = as.Date(c("2021-06-02", "2021-06-05", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-13") ) )
```

I want to store the mean temperature for each period that is in `df2` in a new colomn (`df2$mean.temperature`).

For `ID = 1` from `df2`, the mean temperature would be calculated with the temperatures from `2021-06-01` and `2021-06-02`, witch is `mean(17, 30)`

In other words, I want to get this :

```
    > df2 <- data.frame(ID = c( 1 : 4 ),
                       date.pose = as.Date( c("2021-06-01", "2021-06-03", "2021-06-06", "2021-06-10") ) ,
                       date.withdrawal = as.Date( c("2021-06-03", "2021-06-06", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-13") ),
                       mean.Temperature = c(23.5, 24.3,  20.0, 24.8) )
```

I'm trying to add the ID from `df2` in a new colomn in `df1`. Once I do that, I could aggregate like this :

```
> df3 <- aggregate(df1$temperature, list(df1$ID, df2$date.pose), FUN = mean)
```

I don't know how to add the corresponding ID in df1.
Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Please check that your code runs. `as.date` should be `as.Date`, and your variables need to have the same number of values.

Comment: Same comment for your 2nd `df2`, missing some commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `uncount` from `tidyr` and some joins.

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(days = (date.witdrawal - date.pose + 1) %>% as.integer) %>%
  tidyr::uncount(days, .id = "row") %>%
  transmute(ID, date = date.pose + row - 1) %>%
  left_join(df1) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(mean.Temperature = mean(temperature)) %>% 
  right_join(df2)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     ID mean.Temperature date.pose  date.witdrawal
  <int>            <dbl> <date>     <date>        
1     1             23.5 2021-06-01 2021-06-02    
2     2             24.3 2021-06-03 2021-06-05    
3     3             20   2021-06-06 2021-06-09    
4     4             24.8 2021-06-10 2021-06-13
```

Answer (score 1):

Update. thanks to  @Jon Spring:

Here is how we could do it:

logic:

join both df's by date after long pivoting df1
`arrange` by date and `fill`
then after grouping by ID use `summarise` with `mean()`
and re-join finally:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, values_to = "date") %>% 
  full_join(df1, by= "date") %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  fill(ID, .direction = "down") %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(mean_temp = mean(temperature, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="ID")
```

```
      ID mean_temp date.pose  date.witdrawal
  <int>     <dbl> <date>     <date>        
1     1      23.5 2021-06-01 2021-06-02    
2     2      24.3 2021-06-03 2021-06-05    
3     3      20   2021-06-06 2021-06-09    
4     4      24.8 2021-06-10 2021-06-13
```

Comment: I think the OP wants averages across the range of dates, not just the start and end. Note different desired result for ID 2.